# Infinite loop with Goto

Tags: excel, vba, loops, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone help me, I'm having an error with this part of my code. I'm using Selenium + VBA.

When an element is present on the page I created an IF for it to do some functions and go to the final part of the code by skipping several items through a goto. If this item is not present it continues running the code until the end.

It turns out that when the element is present because of this jump it continues in an infinite loop

Tanks

```
Dim drive As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim test123 As String



ABC = Sheets("Send").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Line = 4

Do Until Cells(Line, 1) = vbNullString

For Line = 4 to ABC

.......

test123 = drive.FindElementsByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]").Count

If test123 > 0 Then

drive.Wait 1000

Cells(2,1).Value = "Not"

drive.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").Click
drive.Wait 1000

GoTo EndCode


ElseIf drive.FindElementsByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]").Count = 0 Then

 
Cells(2,2).Value = "Yes"


Else

End If



EndCode:


Next Line

Loop

drive.Quit
MsgBox "Send OK"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not ever set `Cells(Line, 1)` to anything different than its initial value.

So you start your loop here, with `Line=4`

```
Do Until Cells(Line, 1) = vbNullString
```

Which, if started, implies that `Cells(4, 1)` does not equals `vbNullString`.

Then in the `For Line to ABC` loop you start from 4 upwards and the only cells that have values set in the subsequent code are `Cells(2,1)` and `Cells(2,2)`

i.e. once started, you never change the cell-value for `Cells(4,1)` and hence your `Do until loop` is endless as `Cells(4,1)` never changes...

You can avoid that by either correctly setting `Cells(4,1)` during the loop or by incorporating an exit counter with a preset number of iterations.

```
Dim drive As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim test123 As String


ABC = Sheets("Send").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Line = 4
itt = 0

Do Until (Cells(Line, 1) = vbNullString Or itt > 100)

    For Line = 4 To ABC
    
    'your code        
    
EndCode:

    Next Line
    itt = itt + 1

Loop

drive.Quit
MsgBox "Send OK"


End Sub
```